# How to easily clean dough remains after baking bread?

Tags: cleaning, food, kitchen

I have a strong preference to self made bread. The only issue is that's a dirty job; it leaves dirty hands, a dirty marble working surface, and dirty dishes. How can I clean all of this without filling my kitchen sink waste trap with remains of dough?

Comment: This is a great question ^_^

Comment: @Mooseman This appears to be just a how to question about cleaning. Possibly a good question in the grand scheme of things but it does not show what conventional methods were tried nor demand an unconventional solution. Should the close and flag wording be changed?

Comment: I guess it's obvious, using conventional kitchen sink to clean hands and dishes gets me in the situation where I need to clean the waste trap underneath the kitchen sink once a month, and it's a stinky business that takes about half an hour time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What I do is:**

- After kneeding the bread and setting it in a bowl, rub your hands together over that same bowl or a different bowl . This makes all the bread dough just flake off. Leaving your hands cleaner.
- Take a spatula that is dry and just scrape with it. The dough will come up better if you get the bulk up without water. After scraping the bulk you can scrub it down before it dries, as dried dough is harder to clean.

**To prevent it:**

- I have learned that if you use a little flour when kneeding this takes most of the stickiness away. Instead of that you could grease your hands with cooking oil, this works to make the bread not stick to your hands. Oil works better as flour can wear off faster.
- Wearing gloves. This way you can't feel the dough, but your hands stay clean.
- Put the dough in a plastic bag and knead through their. The bigger and clearer the bag the better. This works perfectly for me, if I want to cook while I am dressed up. My clothes and hands stay clean, plus it is a plus that you have less to wash later.

Comment: The plastic bag idea - +1!

Comment: Great tips, what about if ur sink is filled with washed hands from dough

Answer (score 0):

Put a **little oil on the dough, preferrably on your hand** while kneeding, mix it well..This way, not only you will have a softer dough but also you will have non sticky hands. And to remove the oil from your hand use a soap or a hand wash. Thats it, pretty much simple,works for me
Thanks and hope it works for u!!!

Comment: The hands still have remains of dough and cleaning them with just soap & hand wash will get me in cleaning the sewer once a month.

Comment: Oh No. Just try using oil while u r kneeding.. Just try it once. And ofcourse read my whole answer.

Comment: Your concern **"hands still have remains of dough"** will definitely get solved if only you try using a little bit of oil in your hand while kneading. And as a result of this your hands and the utensil will surely not stick. I am pretty much sure about that. **Give it a try once**, you will surely come to know what  I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

- **Get a flour container and a scale.** Getting flour from a container is less messy than getting it from a bag, and measuring with a scale means you don't need to sift or level, which I've never managed to do cleanly.
- **Add a small amount of oil to the dough.** I usually add a quarter cup of canola oil for roughly 7 cups of flour. One of the benefits is that it makes the dough less sticky, so there's less of a mess in the bowl. All the recipes I've seen that have both a sponge and oil have you add the oil after the sponge, but I have no idea if this is really that important or not.
- **Use gloves while kneading the dough.** Rubber cleaning gloves keep your hands from getting messy when you knead, and you can scrub off the dough with scalding-hot water. If you don't care so much about reusability, disposable gloves from a pharmacy are pretty great. You can knead and then toss out the gloves.
- **Knead in the bowl.** I do it this way and I still get really good bread. Plus you don't have to use a kneading surface or worry about creating more mess in a transfer.
- **After baking, leave the bowl out overnight.** All of the remaining dough will dry out and you can scrape it off into the garbage can.

Answer (score 0):

PAPER towels

All you need to keep to keep kitchen, sink and drains clean and clear of dough.

They just soak everything up and go stright into the bin.

Answer (score 0):

My own preference for homemade bread is to use a bread machine.  These can often be had very cheaply from second hand stores -- mine was $8, plus $15 for a new paddle on eBay, so $23 invested, and I downloaded the user manual for free.  Reasonably modern machines can make a huge variety of different breads, including quick breads, fruit/vegetable loaves, and even jam -- as well as providing kneaded and raised dough ready for loaf forming if you want a loaf that isn't shaped like the machine's pot (see other answers about oiling your hands if you choose to form your own loaves, nothing to clean up other than washing off the oil).

With a machine, you just put the ingredients in the pot and start the machine (on a timer, even -- you can wake up to hot fresh bread for breakfast!).  Your hands never touch the dough, if you let the machine run straight through, so there's nothing to clean off them.  The dough inside the machine's pot is 100% baked into the loaf (you may find you need to scrape down the pot between mixing and kneading with a soft spatula, but the amount of dough you'll need to clean off the spatula is genuinely trivial, and if running overnight the part that didn't get scraped down will just be a crisp crust, easily removed and trashed or eaten).  Just wash the pot and paddle after removing the loaf, and you're ready to start again.

And, as you already know, the ingredients cost for fresh homemade bread is about a quarter that of economy brand bread from a grocery store.  Even if you pay full retail for the machine, it'll pay for itself in a short time (hint: get your bread flour in a large bag -- 50 lb. costs about as much as two 10 lb bags -- and when you open the bag, transfer the flour to plastic buckets).

Answer (score 0):

Put a bit more flour into your mixture until it comes away clean from the bowl. I do this inside the food processor, because it is a devil to get clean otherwise. When you take the dough out you press it all together and it comes out in one piece.

When kneading or rolling out, use plenty of flour (I have it in a shaker) whenever it starts to stick.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a removable waste trap that sits in the sink, and clean that after each use.